# Convert Swift Encodable class typed as Any to dictionary

Tags: swift, serialization, codable

In connection with [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390160/nsuserdefaults-storing-struct-class-with-only-property-list-compliant-types-in) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385105/prevent-nstableview-from-saving-new-row-until-user-fills-values) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375863/nsuserdefaultscontroller-attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-n), I decided to subclass `NSArrayController` in order to achieve the desired behavior.

```
class NSPresetArrayController: NSArrayController {
    override func addObject(_ object: Any) {
        if let preset = object as? Preset {
            super.addObject(["name": preset.name, "value": preset.value])
        } else {
            super.addObject(object)
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but what if I wanted something that works for any `Encodable` class, and not just one with two properties called `name` and `value`?

Basically, the problem is creating a dictionary from a class, where the keys are the property names, and the values are the values of these properties.

I tried writing something like this:

```
class NSPresetArrayController: NSArrayController {
    override func addObject(_ object: Any) {
        if let encodableObject = object as? Encodable {
            let data = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(encodableObject)
            let any = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil)

            super.addObject(any)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get a compile error:

```
Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Encodable)'
1. Expected an argument list of type '(Value)'
```

How do I fix this so it compiles?

Comment: This boils down to casting the object from `Any` to the "real" type...but I honestly don't know how to do that. I'm sure someone does, though. Assuming that it's possible.

Comment: You cannot fix this. The argument of `encode` must be a concrete type, not a protocol. Cocoa Bindings which are widely related to Objective-C and Swift generics don't work together. You have to find a way without bindings or without generics.

Comment: Well, you could statically enumerate the types you will be encoding... :barf:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [protocols don't always conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878). `PropertyListEncoder`'s [`encode(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistencoder/2895057-encode) method expects a `Value : Encodable` argument:

```
func encode<Value : Encodable>(_ value: Value) throws -> Data
```

However the `Encodable` type itself is currently unable to satisfy this constraint (but it might well do in a future version of the language).

As explored in the linked Q&A (and [also here](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-encode-objects-of-unknown-type/12253/5)), one way to work around this limitation is to *open* the `Encodable` value in order to dig out the underlying concrete type, which we can substitute for `Value`. We can do this with a protocol extension, and use a wrapper type in order to encapsulate it:

```
extension Encodable {
  fileprivate func openedEncode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
    try container.encode(self)
  }
}

struct AnyEncodable : Encodable {
  var value: Encodable
  init(_ value: Encodable) {
    self.value = value
  }
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try value.openedEncode(to: &container)
  }
}
```

Applied to your example:

```
class NSPresetArrayController : NSArrayController {
  override func addObject(_ object: Any) {
    guard let object = object as? Encodable else { 
      // Not encodable, maybe do some error handling.
      return 
    }
    do {
      let encoded = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(AnyEncodable(object))
      let cocoaPropertyList = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: encoded, format: nil)
      super.addObject(cocoaPropertyList)
    } catch {
      // Couldn't encode. Do some error handling.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the value that you pass to `encode(_:)` has to be a concrete type that implements `Encodable`. This means you need to recover the object's real type from the `Any` that you have. In order to cast, you must have a statically-specified type to which you are casting. You can't say `object as! type(of: object)`, in other words; you have to say `object as? MyClass` (or in a generic context you can say `object as? T`).

Therefore, I believe that the only way to get around this is to statically enumerate the types you are working with, like so:

```
import Foundation

struct S : Encodable {
    let i: Int
}

struct T : Encodable {
    let f: Float
}

struct U : Encodable {
    let b: Bool
}

func plistObject(from encodable: Any) -> Any? {
    let encoded: Data?
    switch encodable {
        case let s as S:
            encoded = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(s)
        case let t as T:
            encoded = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(t)
        case let u as U:
            encoded = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(u)
        default:
            encoded = nil
    }

    guard let data = encoded else { return nil }

    return try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data,
                                                       options: [],
                                                       format: nil)
}
```

Needless to say, this is rather gross. It's inflexible, repetitive boilerplate. I'm not sure I can actually *recommend* its use. It's an answer to the literal question, not necessarily a solution to the problem.

Comment: You can open the `Encodable` value using a protocol extension in order to get the underlying concrete type with which to satisfy the generic placeholder, see my answer :)